# Android Studio Emulator failed to initialize WHPX: Function not implemented

Tags: android-studio

I am running the emulator for the first time whenever I click on run app it gives the following errors.

```
Emulator: C:\Users\rime\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86\qemu-system-x86_64.exe:failed to initialize WHPX: Function not implemented
```

I've already checked the SDK manager and the emulator is already selected but still having the same problem.

Comment: have you updated to the latest version?

Comment: The Version is already updated.